# Where In Not - doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

```
FIRST:
id | name
1  | sss
2  | ddd
5  | fff

  $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('First a');

  return $q->execute();

SECOND:
id | first_id | name
 ....


  $two = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Second a')
    ->whereInNot(first_id, $q) // ???????
    ;

  return $two->execute();
```

How can i get all data from table SECOND without first_id existing in table FIRST?

Comment: Problems with your code include: the first query returns a Doctrine_Collection (like a list of Doctrine_Records), which is NOT an array you can feed into the second query.  Also the method you needed is "whereNotIn()" rather than "whereInNot()".  I've provided two examples in my answer for how you can code this, depending on whether you actually needed to know the first_ids or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach one (similar to your example code):

```
// Retrieve ONLY the id, and use hydration mode that produces a simple array of results.
$first_ids = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('f.id')
  ->from('First f')
  ->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);

$two = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Second s')
  ->whereNotIn('first_id', $first_ids);
return $two->execute();
```

Another approach to get the same result in a single compound query:

```
$two = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Second s')
  ->where('first_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM First)');
return $two->execute();
```